# Creating forums - resizing an image's HTML via HTML/PHP?

Tags: php, html

This may be hard to describe...but...

I created some simple PHP forums and I have the ability for users to post image links and I want the image to appear on the page. BUT...my forum posts are inside an iframe and if the width of the post is too wide it would cut off the side so I want images to only be so wide. Any concepts for getting the image to fit? I wonder if there's some auto resizing option in HTML or a way for PHP to get the file width/height remotely and generate the HTML for it?

Comment: Try a CSS class `.image_width { width:100%; }` or `style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width:100%; max-width:600px; max-height:300px"` (example pixel sizes)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `max-width` attribute in css eg:

```
iframe img{max-width: 500px;}/*or whatever your max wants to be*/
```

and in php you can use

```
<?php
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($yourfilename);
```

you might need to wrap `getimagesize` in a if because it will cause it to return false on failure